# Swift Convert Any To Data

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm using facebook sdk to log users in ,
every ting is going well except that after user is logged in i make a request to graph api so it returns user's data .

when i try to parse user data to `codable` using `JSONEncoder()` an error occurred !

the error is

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Any?' to expected argument type 'Data'
```

Full code :

```
import SwiftUI
import FBSDKLoginKit

struct AccountView: View {
    @ObservedObject var loginManager = UserLoginManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        if(!loginManager.logged)
        {
            Button(action: {
                self.loginManager.facebookLogin()
            }) {
                Text("Continue with Facebook")
            }
        }
        else{
            Text((loginManager.userData as AnyObject).email!)
            
        }
        
    }
}

struct AccountView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AccountView()
    }
}


class UserLoginManager: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var logged:Bool = false
    @Published var userData:Any = []
    let loginManager = LoginManager()
    func facebookLogin() {
        //        loginManager.set
        loginManager.logIn(permissions: [.publicProfile, .email], viewController: nil) { loginResult in
            switch loginResult {
            case .failed(let error):
                print(error)
            case .cancelled:
                print("User cancelled login.")
            case .success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let accessToken):
                print("Logged in! \(grantedPermissions) \(declinedPermissions) \(String(describing: accessToken))")
                GraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "name,picture,email"]).start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                    if (error == nil){
                        let facebookResponse = try? newJSONDecoder().decode(FacebookResponse.self, from: result)
                        self.userData = facebookResponse!
                        
                        self.logged = true
                    }
                    else{
                        print("\\\\\\\\")
                        print(error as Any)
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}



// MARK: - FacebookResponse
struct FacebookResponse: Codable {
    let email: String?
    let id: Int?
    let name: String?
    let picture: Picture?
}

// MARK: - Picture
struct Picture: Codable {
    let data: DataClass?
}

// MARK: - DataClass
struct DataClass: Codable {
    let height, isSilhouette: Int?
    let url: String?
    let width: Int?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case height
        case isSilhouette = "is_silhouette"
        case url, width
    }
}
```

and the `newJSONDecoder()`:

```
func newJSONDecoder() -> JSONDecoder {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    if #available(iOS 10.0, OSX 10.12, tvOS 10.0, watchOS 3.0, *) {
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
    }
    return decoder
}
```

Hint :

```
let facebookResponse = try? newJSONDecoder().decode(FacebookResponse.self, from: result as! Data)
```

Doesn’t worked

Comment: What's the definition of `start(completionHandler:)` or its doc? Does it parse it already into a `[String: Any]`with JSONSerialization? Could you print it and show the result?

Answer (score 4):

Use `JSONSerialization.data(` to convert `Any` to `Data`

```
do { 
    let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: result, options: [])  
    self.userData = try newJSONDecoder().decode(FacebookResponse.self, from: data) 
    self.logged = true
 }
 catch {
   print(error)
 }
```